# Limit concurrent execution of an application process using database

Tags: java, database, postgresql, concurrency

I was asked to implement an *"access policy"* to limit the amount of concurrent executions of a certaing process within an application (NOT a web application) which has direct connection to the database.

The application is running in several machines, and if more than a user tries to call the process, only one execution should be allowed at a given time, and the other must return an error message (NOT wait for the first execution to end).

Although I'm using **Java/Postgres**, is sort of a general question.

Given that I have the same application running in several machines, the simplest solution I can think of is implementing some sort of "database flag".

Something like checking whether the process is currently active:

```
SELECT Active FROM Process
```

If it's active, return a 'concurrent access policy error'. If not, activate it:

```
UPDATE Process SET Active = 'Y'
```

Once the execution is finished, simply update the active flag:

```
UPDATE Process SET Active = 'N'
```

However, I've encountered a major issue:

- If I don't use a DB transaction in order to change the active flag, and the application is killed, the the active flag will remain with the Y value forever.
- If I use a DB transaction, the first point is solved.  However, the change of the active flag in a host (from N to Y) will only be visible after the commit, so the other hosts will never read active with Y value and therefore execute anyway.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just some first thoughts: You can set the flag in a separate transaction (maybe in combination with explicit locking) or you could have a look at e.g. hazelcast for some sort of cluster-wide lock (although this might be overkill for your application).

Comment: Not directly related to the question but you could benefit from using an `INSERT` instead of an `UPDATE`. When the first user calls the process, a new row should be inserted in the DB. When the second user calls the process, his `INSERT` using the same primary key should fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't bother with an active flag, instead simply lock a row based on the user ID. Keep that row locked in a dedicated transaction/connection. When the other user tries to lock the row (using SELECT ... FOR UPDATE) you'll get an error, and you can report it.

If the process holding the transaction fails, the lock is freed. If it quits, the lock is freed. If the DB is rebooted, the lock is freed.

Win all around.

Comment: Yes! Definitely the simplest and most straightforward solution.  Works perfectly.  To complete the solution, I had to use the NOWAIT option with the SELECT ... FOR UPDATE in order to get an exception when the second process tries to get the lock.   Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having only a simple Y/N flag, put the timestamp at which active as been set, and have your client application set it regularly (say every minute, or every five minute). Then if a client crashes, other clients will have to wait just over that time limit, and then assume that client is dead and take over. This is just some kind of "heartbeat" mechanism to check the client that started the process is still alive.

A simpler solution would be to configure the database to only accept one connection at the time?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if a RDBMS is the best system to solve this kind of issue. But I recently implemented a similar thing in SQL Server 2012. So here's what I learned from that experience.

In general, I mean in principle, you need an atomic operation "check the value, update the value (of one single record)" i.e. an atomic `SELECT/UPDATE`. This makes the matter complex. And because normally there's no such standard single atomic operation in the RDBMSs, you can get familiar with and use `ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`.

This is how I implemented it in SQL Server 2012, and I've seriously tested it, it's working fine. I have a table called `DistributedLock`, each record from it represents a logical lock. The operations I allow are `tryLock` and `releaseLock` (these are implemented as two stored procedures). The `tryLock` is non-blocking (practically non-blocking). If it succeeds, it returns some ID/stamp to the caller who can use that ID/stamp later to call `releaseLock`. If one calls `releaseLock` without actually holding the lock (without having the latest ID/stamp that is), the call succeeds and does nothing, otherwise (if the caller has the lock) the call succeeds and releases the lock held by the caller. I also have support for timeouts. So if some process grabs the ID/stamp of a given lock/record, and forgets to release it, it will expire automatically after some time.

Here is how the table looks like.

```
[DistributedLockID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL -- surrogate PK 
[ResourceID] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL -- resource/lock logical identifier 
[Duration] [int] NOT NULL 
[AcquisitionTime] [datetime] NULL 
[RecordStamp] [bigint] NOT NULL
```

I guess you can figure out the rest (or try, and then ping me if you get stuck).

Comment: +1 and thank for the detailed explanation.  I simply marked Will Hartung as the correct answer because it's a very simple yet useful Postgres solution.